# Which stripe webhook event is triggered after preauthorized payment expires after seven days?

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I am using stripe's payment intent to preauthorize and capture funds later. However I am confused about which webhook event is called after seven days when preauthorization expires. Is it `payment_intent.canceled` ? I am currently using test data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [docs](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/capture-later):

> If the payment is not captured in this time, the authorization is
> canceled and the funds are released. When this happens, the
> PaymentIntent status transitions to canceled.

Meaning you'd get a `payment_intent.canceled` webhook event.